# What's the difference between Windows Task Scheduler, Hangfire, and Quartz.net?

Tags: quartz.net, hangfire, windows-task-scheduler

I always need to develop some periodically job. How should I choose between Windows Task Scheduler or Hangfire? What's the difference between Windows Task Scheduler and Hangfire (or Quartz.net)?

Answer (score 19):

Windows Task Scheduler sits outside the ASP.NET environment.  It can be used to run any type of Windows program.  To add Windows Tasks, you need login access to the server.

Hangfire generally runs inside an IIS process (although it can also run in a Console application).  The main benefit of Hangfire is that the developer doesn't need login access to the IIS server to create a scheduled task - particularly useful in an IIS environment hosted by a vendor where server access is not available.